# Styling of columns in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrapping

I'm trying to style two columns in bootstrap so they have the same height, there is a small gap between them and they have a background color too.

[Boxes have the same row height and desired gap but the background doesn't stretch to the whole height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nljLO.png)
[image]

I managed to apply the css for same height, but struggle with applying the color to the background.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```css
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.row-eq-height > [class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.white-box {
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
 
}
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-eq-height">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-justify">
                <div class="white-box">
                    <h5>SOME TITLE</h5>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
                    </p>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-justify">
                <div class="white-box">
                    <h5>SOME TITLE</h5>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.                            
                    </p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-sm">Continued &gt;&gt;</a></p>
                </div>

         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: welcome to S.O. Provide code so others can help/suggest/improve .

Comment: please show what you tried